# javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException and error page not working

Tags: ajax, jsf, viewexpiredexception

I set up my web app as follows:

```
 <error-page>
        <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
        <location>/WEB-INF/include/viewExpired.html</location>
</error-page>
```

so that the above error page be displayed when the viewExpiredException is thrown.

However, when I restart the server and submit an ajax request on an "left-open" page, the exception is thrown in the console and my error page is not displayed.

Here is that stack trace from the console:

```
javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException: viewId:/contact.jsf - La vue /contact.jsf na pas pu être restaurée.
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:200)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:111)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:312)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:630)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:436)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:374)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:302)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:110)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:113)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at com.jeanbaptistemartin.util.DisableUrlSessionFilter.doFilter(DisableUrlSessionFilter.java:70)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:525)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:286)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:845)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

anyone has got any clue please?

Thanks in advance,
J.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to handle Ajax errors on the standard JSF 2.0 implementation? The standard JSF implementation doesn't provide a ready-to-use component for this. In PrimeFaces for example, you could use [`<p:ajaxStatus>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/pprAjaxStatus.jsf) component for this. The [JSF 2.0 specification](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr314/index.html) however outlines the following in chapter 13.3.6.2:

> #### 13.3.6.2 Handling Errors For All Ajax Requests
>
> The JavaScript API provides the `jsf.ajax.addOnError` function that can be used to register a JavaScript function that will be notified when an error occurs for any Ajax request/response. Refer to Section 14.4 “Registering Callback Functions” for more details. The `jsf.ajax.addOnError` function accepts a JavaScript function argument that will be
>   notified when errors occur during any Ajax request/response cycle. [P1-start-event] The implementation must ensure the
>   JavaScript function that is registered must be called in accordance with the errors outlined in Section TABLE 14-5
>   “Errors”

You can find [here](https://jamesgdriscoll.wordpress.com/2010/02/09/jsf-2-ajax-events-and-errors/) a blog of one of the Mojarra developers which contains basic examples how to show the ajax status. Here's an extract of relevance:

> ```
> <h3> Status:</h3>
> <textarea id="statusArea" cols="40" rows="10" readonly="readonly" />
> ```
>
> A simple textarea, not even hooked
>   into the backend server data model.
>
> Then in our javascript (for the demo,
>   in a separately loaded file, though it
>   could just as easily be in page) we
>   have:
>
> ```
> var statusUpdate = function statusUpdate(data) {
>     var statusArea = document.getElementById("statusArea");
>     var text = statusArea.value;
>     text = text + "Name: "+data.source.id;
>     if (data.type === "event") {
>         text = text +" Event: "+data.name+"\n";
>     } else {  // otherwise, it's an error
>         text = text + " Error: "+data.name+"\n";
>     }
>     statusArea.value = text;
> };
>
> // Setup the statusUpdate function to hear all events on the page
> jsf.ajax.addOnEvent(statusUpdate);
> jsf.ajax.addOnError(statusUpdate);
> ```

You could it as well to redirect to an error page using JS.

```
window.location = '/errors/500.xhtml';
```

Comment: Hello BalusC! The exception I am specifically interested in is the viewExpired exception. Is there any way for this specific exception to be "trapped" by the web container and for my error page to be displayed?

Comment: Hello again BalusC. I implemented your solution. It works. Thanks. Julien.