# ViewExpiredException, Page could not be restored

Tags: session, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, glassfish, viewexpiredexception

I've tried to follow different posts on how to handle the `ViewExpiredException` in Mojarra 2.1.0 (with RichFaces 4) on GlassFish 3.1. But what I define in `web.xml` doesn't seams to have any effect. I use form base security and the user has to logon to access the content. I just want Glassfish (catalina) to redirect the user to a simple JSF page when the session times-out, with a link back to the login page.

I always get the the following error message;

```
javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException: viewId:/app_user/activity/List.xhtml - View /app_user/activity/List.xhtml could not be restored.
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:202)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:113)
```

Who can I redirect the user when the user session has timed-out and trap the exception in the server log ?

Greetings, Chris.

**layout.xhtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">

    <h:head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <!-- Had no effect
        <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
        <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
        <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
        -->      
        <h:outputStylesheet name="css/default.css"/>
        <h:outputStylesheet name="css/cssLayout.css"/>

        <title>
            <h:outputText value="Partner Tapestry - " /> <ui:insert name="title">Browser Title</ui:insert>
        </title>
    </h:head>

    <h:body>
        <div id="top" >
            <ui:insert name="top">Top Default</ui:insert>
        </div>

        <div id="messages">
            <rich:messages id="messagePanel"/>
        </div>

        <div id="content">
            <ui:insert name="content">Content Default</ui:insert>
        </div>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

**web.xml**

```
...
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        2
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<error-page>
    <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
    <location>/faces/resources/sessionExpired.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
...
```

**login.xhtml**

```
<ui:composition template="/resources/masterLayout.xhtml"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j">

    <ui:define name="title">
        <h:outputText value="Login"></h:outputText>
    </ui:define>
    <ui:define name="top">
        <h:outputText value="Welcome" />
    </ui:define>

    <ui:define name="content">         
        <h:form>
            <h:panelGrid columns="3">
                <h:outputLabel for="username" value="Username" />
                <h:inputText id="username" value="#{userController.userAuthentication}" />
                <br />
                <h:outputLabel for="password" value="Password" />
                <h:inputSecret id="password" value="#{userController.passwordAuthentication}" />
                <br />
                <h:outputText value=" " />
                <a4j:commandButton action="#{userController.login()}" value="Login"/>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

finally **sessionExpire.xhtml**

```
<ui:composition template="/resources/masterLayout.xhtml"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j">

    <ui:define name="title">
        <h:outputText value="Session Exired"></h:outputText>
    </ui:define>
    <ui:define name="top">
        <h:outputText value="Session expired, please login again" />
    </ui:define>

    <ui:define name="content"> 
        <h:form>           
            <a4j:commandLink action="/resources/login?faces-redirect=true" value="Login" />
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem by following this link on implementing a [ExceptionHandlerFactory](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/edburns/archive/2009/09/03/dealing-gracefully-viewexpiredexception-jsf2). A nice solution where you can have an exception navigation rule, but maybe a bit long. Thanks for the help @BalusC.

Comment: This is also covered in the question of the 2nd "See also" link of my answer.

Answer (score 5):

Your approach should work perfectly fine for synchronous POST requests. However, you're using asynchronous (ajax) POST requests. Exceptions on ajax requests needs to be handled by either the `jsf.ajax.addOnError` init function in JavaScript or a custom [`ExceptionHandler`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExceptionHandler.html).

#### See also

- [javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException and error page not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677279/javax-faces-application-viewexpiredexception-and-error-page-not-working)
- [JSF: Cannot catch ViewExpiredException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2980708/jsf-cannot-catch-viewexpiredexception)